# Error when reading stories: storybook is loading for too long

Tags: applitools

I am trying to add applitools/eyes-storybook to run existing storybook visual tests. but getting below error.

```
⠋ Starting storybook server/Users/testuser/project/node_modules/.bin/start-storybook
✔ Storybook was started
✖ Error when reading stories: storybook is loading for too long
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Matt and I work on the Applitools support team. I see you're running into an issue with our Storybook SDK.

In cases like this, we'd typically ask for more information as well as verbose logging. Unfortunately, the logs will contain your API key so we can't have you post them here. Could you please open up a support ticket [here](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)? Then, I'll be able to grab the required information and help you resolve this issue.

Thanks! Matt